# MVC Model Duplication in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a need for models that are mapped to their corresponding data tables, and every time the models/tables are updated, I need to mapped the changes to the archived tables for historical references. For example -

```
[Table("A")]
public class A
{
    [Key]       
    public int A_Id { get; set; }       

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Table("A_History")]
public class A_History
{
    [Key]   
    public int A_History_Id { get; set; }       

    public int A_Id { get; set; }       

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So every time Table A is modified, I need to add an entry to A_History with an exact copy of the new or original data. Is there a generic way to do this, such that I can pass in a string as the Model name to a method or class, and the method can automatically loop through all the properties of the Model class, and map them to another class to be added by matching the names?

Comment: sounds like you are looking for something like Automapper...

Comment: It may be a good idea to store the historical data in a different database

Comment: I have not used Automapper before, but from what I read, isn't that for mapping ViewModel to Model? As for historical data in a different database, what would be the advantage of that? Are you concerned about the size of the data growing to very large? Speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below uses reflection, so be careful of performance. If performance is a very important aspect then it might be better to actually map properties one by one, but if you're looking at generic implementation you could try the below snippet.

```
// object instances
A sourceInstance = new A();
A_History destInstance = new A_History();
MapSourceValuesToDestination(sourceInstance, destInstance);

private void MapSourceValuesToDestination(object sourceObject, object destinationObject)
{
    //get all properties
    PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = typeof (sourceObject).GetProperties();
    PropertyInfo[] destinationProperties = typeof (destinationObject).GetProperties();

    // foreach in source
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in sourceProperties)
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            string propertyName = property.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                // get destination property matched by name
                PropertyInfo matchingProperty = destinationProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));    
                if (matchingProperty != null)
                {
                    // get source value
                    object sourceValue = property.GetValue(sourceInstance);
                    if (sourceValue != null)
                    {
                        // set source value to destination
                        matchingProperty.SetValue(destInstance, sourceValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have to try it out when I get a chance. Yes I am looking for a generic implementation because every data table that gets updated requires an update/archive of the corresponding history table.

Comment: I have not tried this approach yet. I have tried the Auto Mapper and it has worked wonder. I will give this approach a try in the coming week. I will post an update by next week once I give it a try. I like to know if it will work as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If your history model has the same properties as the model that holds the history of then you can do something like.

1. Add the `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package and do.
2. Add the code shown bellow.

   ```
   A model = new A();
   //.....
   // add data to the model
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
   A_History historyModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A_History>(json);
   ```
3. Now your history model will have filled all the properties that are the same with the A model.